# How prove this $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin \frac{1}{x-r_n} }{2}\right)^n$ such follow condition?

Tags: analysis

**Question:**

let $r_{1},r_{2},\cdots.$ is the interval $[0, 1]$ rational sequence  in a line,

and define:

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sin{\left(\dfrac{1}{x-r_{n}}\right)}}{2}\right)^n &x\in R-Q\\
> \displaystyle\sum_{n\neq m}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sin{\left(\dfrac{1}{x-r_{n}}\right)}}{2}\right)^n&x=r_{m}\in Q
> \end{cases}$$
>   show that:

Then function $f(x)$ such this follow three conditions:

> (1): $x\in [0,1]$
>
> (2):
>   such $f(x)$ is continuous at all irrationals, discontinuous at all rationals;
>
> (3):and $f$   have many  infinite number discontinuity point of the second kind in $[0,1]$

the problem is from this:[How take example such this three conditions.is continuous at all irrationals, discontinuous at all rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/564993/how-take-example-such-this-three-conditions-is-continuous-at-all-irrationals-di?rq=1)

I feel my example is such this three conditions, But I can't prove it (2),(3),especially
(3).

can you someone can help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do I correctly understand that $r_1,r_2,\dots$ are supposed to enumerate all the rational numbers in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$?

Comment: I assumed this in the answer below. It is simple to modify the argument for the case when $(r_n)$ is any sequence, such that for each $a$ there are at most finitely many $n$ such that $r_n = a$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove (dis)continuity, you can begin with the following observation:

**Observation:** Suppose that $I = (a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ is an interval of length $2 \varepsilon$ such that $r_n \not \in I$ for $n \leq N$, for some given $N$. Let $J = (a-\varepsilon/2,a+\varepsilon/2)$ be an interval of length $\varepsilon$ with the same centre as $I$. Then, there exists a constant $C = C_\varepsilon$ such that for any $x \in J$ it holds that $|f(x) - f(a)| < C |x-a| + \frac{4}{2^N}$.

**Proof:** First, use "infinite triangle inequality":
$$ |f(x) - f(a)| \leq \sum_{n} |s_n(x) - s_n(a)| = 
\sum_{n \leq N} |s_n(x) - s_n(a)| + \sum_{n > N} |s_n(x) - s_n(a)| $$
where we define
$$s_n(x) := \begin{cases} \left(\frac{\sin(1/(x-r_n))}{2}\right)^n,& \ x \neq r_n\\ 0, & x = r_n \end{cases}$$
We bound the two sums above separately. For the second sum, it will suffice to notice that $| s_n(y) | \leq 1/2^n$, and hence $|s_n(x) - s_n(a)| \leq 1/2^{n-1}$. Summing over $n = N+1,N+2,\dots$ we find $$ \sum_{n > N} |s_n(x) - s_n(a)| \leq \frac{1}{2^{N-2}}.$$
For the first summand, first note that for $n \leq N$ we have $r_n \not \in I$, and hence $ s_n(x) = \left(\frac{\sin(1/(x-r_n))}{2}\right)^n$ for $x \in I$. In particular, $s_n$ is a differentiable function, and we can compute the derivative:
$$ s_n'(x) = \frac{n}{2^n} \frac{1}{(r_n-x)^2} \cos\frac{1}{x-r_n} \sin^{n-1}\frac{1}{x-r_n}.$$
For $x \in J$ we know that $|r_n-x| > \varepsilon/2$, and clearly $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ are bounded by $1$ in absolute value. It follows that $|s_n'(x)| \leq \frac{n}{2^n} \frac{4}{\varepsilon^2}$.

By the mean value theorem, you can approximate for $x \in J$ : $$|s_n(x) - s_n(a)| \leq |x-a| \cdot \max_{y \in J} s_n'(y) \leq |x-a| \frac{n}{2^n} \frac{4}{\varepsilon^2}.$$
Summing this over $n < N$, and letting $C_\varepsilon = \frac{4}{\varepsilon^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}$ we get:
$$ \sum_{n \leq N} |s_n(x) - s_n(a)| \leq C |x-a|$$
Thus, putting this together, we get:
$$|f(x) - f(a)| \leq C |x-a| + \frac{4}{2^N},$$
as stated at the beginning. $\square$

Let us see how the claim follows from the above observation.

First, take $a \in [0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Let $\eta > 0$; our goal is to find $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|x -a| <\delta$ then also $|f(x) - f(a)| < \eta$. First, select $N$ sufficiently large that $4/2^N < \eta/2$. Next, take $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small that in $I = (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ there are no $r_n$ with $n \leq N$. If $|x-a|<\varepsilon/2$ we now have by the observation above:
$$ |f(x) - f(a)| < C |x-a| + \eta/2$$
It suffices to pick $\delta$ so that $C \delta < \eta/2$ (and $\delta < \varepsilon/2$), and we are done!

If $a = r_m$ is rational, then we can exploit the reasoning above. A little informally, let $\tilde{f}$ be a function which is defined exactly the same as $f$, with the exception that we skip the $m$-th summand: $\tilde{f}(x) = \sum_{n \neq m} s_n(x)$. Now, the same argument as we just used shows that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous at $a$. However, $f(x) = s_,(x) + \tilde{f}(x)$, and clearly $s_m(x)$ is discontinuous at $a$. Thus, $f(x)$ is also discontinuous at $a$.

Moreover, $f$ has the same type of discontinuity as $s_m$ (adding a continuous function does not alter the type of discontinuity), so we have proved that $f$ has a discontinuity point of the second kind.